# Twitter Trends API weekly.json causing error "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"

Tags: php, json, twitter

I have the following PHP code:

```
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $obj = json_decode($result);

        foreach ($obj[0]->trends as $trend) echo utf8_decode($trend->name);
```

which works fine for URL #1 (into the variable $URL):

http://api.twitter.com/1/trends/1.json?exclude=hashtags

but causes an error "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array" for URL #2:
http://api.twitter.com/1/trends/weekly.json?exclude=hashtags

I have searched for a while, but can't figure out a code to fix this and handle both URLs.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What's your PHP version?

Comment: @BoltClock  PHP Version 5.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first URL serves a JSON array as the root element. It contains an object, which in turn contains an array called `trends`. You're correctly accessing it in your `foreach` like so:

```
$obj[0]->trends
```

But the second URL serves a JSON object as the root element, which contains an object called `trends`. Thus you can't use `$obj[0]` to access what's in that root object. The object contains an array of trend names for each day of the week so you need to nest two `foreach` loops to get to the trend info:

```
// Loop through each day of the week
foreach ($obj->trends as $date => $trends) {
    // Get each trending topic for this day
    foreach ($trends as $trend) {
        echo utf8_decode($trend->name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback; I understand I need different code, but how do I access the trends name in the case of URL#2?